# Angular 5 + ag-grid - Using ag-grid with media query

Tags: angular, ag-grid

On large screen I use `sizeColumnsToFit()` to fit ag-grid table to the whole screen, but when in mobile screen size, I want to use `autoSizeColumns()` because `sizeColumnsToFit()` will make all columns very tiny. Therefore, is it possible to set specific screen size by media query to achieve this dynamically? Or does anyone has other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got a solution that works pretty well for now. I put a condition in `onGridReady()` that detects width of screen size initially, so it can dynamically fire up either `autoSizeColumns()` or `sizeColumnsToFit()`

```
  onGridReady(params) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.gridApi = params.api;
      this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;   
      const eGridDiv = document.querySelector('.my-grid');
      const allColumnIds = [];
      if (eGridDiv.clientWidth <= 768) {
        this.gridColumnApi.getAllColumns().forEach(function(column) {
          allColumnIds.push(column.colId);
        });
        this.gridColumnApi.autoSizeColumns(allColumnIds);
      } else {
        params.api.sizeColumnsToFit();
      }      
    }, 500);
  }

<ag-grid-angular 
style="width: auto; height: 60vh;"
class="ag-theme-balham my-grid"
[rowData]="data" 
[columnDefs]="columns"
[enableColResize]="true"
(gridReady)="onGridReady($event)">
</ag-grid-angular>
```